# Patch value with a string

Tags: angular

How can I patch a field value with a string? This doesn't work for some reason:

```
test = "myForm.controls.graphicUrl";
this[test].patchValue("hello");
```

Comment: If you're going to downvote to close at least tell me what your reason is. This is an acceptable question to ask.

Comment: JavaScript does not work this way:https://i.imgur.com/1J0zjZX.png

Comment: There are no downvotes on this question. I voted to close because there is not enough information here to debug. How are we supposed to know what "doesn't work"?

Comment: I personally use Lodash to perform things like that : https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
this.myForm.controls[graphicUrl].patchValue("hello");
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't answer the question. I have to patch it via a string.

Comment: Ok, you can have onllu `graphicUrl` in the string... Modified the answer. Will it solve the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:
https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#get

If you have multiple FormGroups, consider making a root FormGroup

```
this.rootForm = this.fb.build({
    myForm:this.myForm,
    otherForm:this.otherForm
})
//then from your example:
const dotSeparatedPath = "myForm.graphicUrl"
this.rootForm.get(dotSeparatedPath).patchValue("hello")
//you can also pass an object as a parameter to the whole rootForm
const formValues= {
    myForm:{
        graphicUrl:"hello"
    }
}
/* only graphUrl will be changes since the other keys in the object are not defined. */
this.rootForm.patchValue(formValues)
```